# Output of the program is different from what it was expected

Tags: c

I have a binary tree program. And Im trying to test some parts of the program to check if the input is icual to the expected output. But Im having two issues as explained below.

For example Im trying to execute this test below, and show "same" when the test pass and "not same" when it fails.

```
INPUT                                                      OUTPUT
Insert 10 nodes(55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1)  55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1
Insert node 4                                        55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1, 4
print_preorder()                                     55, 31, 1, 4, 49, 39, 47, 64, 65, 98, 97
search(55)                                           55
```

The issue is that Im giving the correct inputs and I get always the result below, the last test shows always "Not same" and when a test shows "not same" the other part of the code is not executed.

```
same
same
not same
```

And I would expect:

```
same
same
same
55
```

And the other issue is that when I get this message "not same" the other code below is not executed.

EXAMPLE:

```
int main(void) {
    node *root = NULL;
    int i, j;
    node *tmp;
    int arr[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    int arrExp[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)] = {0};
    int arrExp2[] = {55, 31, 1, 4, 49, 39, 47, 64, 65, 98, 97};

    int *aporder = arr;
    int *ap = arrExp;


    // insert 10 nodes on tree
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        insert(&root, arr[i]);

    // check if the array elements are the same of the tree
    outToArray(root, &ap);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    // insert node 4 on tree
    insert(&root, 4);

    // check if tree nodes are now icual to arrExp that has now the 4 node
    outToArray(root, &ap);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    // check if pre order display is icual to ArrExp2
    outToArrayPorder(root, &aporder);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp2[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    tmp = search(&root, 55);
    if (tmp)
    {
        printf("Searched node=%d\n", tmp->data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data Not found in tree.\n");
    }

    /* Deleting all nodes of tree */
    deltree(root);

    return 0;
}



   int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int x = *(int *)a;
    int y = *(int *)b;
    return x < y ? -1 : x > y;
}

void outToArrayPorder(node *tree, int **arr){
    //pre-order output
    if(tree){
        *(*arr)++ = tree->data;
        outToArrayPorder(tree->left, arr);
        outToArrayPorder(tree->right, arr);
    }
}

void outToArray(node *tree, int **arr){
    //Write elements of tree to the array.
    if(tree){
        outToArray(tree->left, arr);
        *(*arr)++ = tree->data;
        outToArray(tree->right, arr);
    }
}


int  print_preorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        printf("%d ",tree->data);
        int left = print_preorder(tree->left);
        int right = print_preorder(tree->right);
        return  left+right+1;
    } else{
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Complete program:

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

struct bin_tree {
    int data;
    struct bin_tree * right, * left;
};
typedef struct bin_tree node;

void insert(node ** tree, int val)
{
    node *temp = NULL;
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
        temp->left = temp->right = NULL;
        temp->data = val;
        *tree = temp;
        return;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->left, val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        insert(&(*tree)->right, val);
    }

}

int  print_preorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        printf("%d ",tree->data);
        int left = print_preorder(tree->left);
        int right = print_preorder(tree->right);
        return  left+right+1;
    } else{
        return 0;
    }

}

int print_inorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {

        int left = print_inorder(tree->left);
        printf("%d ",tree->data);
        int right = print_inorder(tree->right);
        return left+right+1;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
int print_postorder(node * tree)
{
    if (tree) {
        int left = print_postorder(tree->left);
        int right = print_postorder(tree->right);
        printf("%d ",tree->data);
        return left + right + 1;
    } else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void deltree(node * tree)
{
    if (tree)
    {
        deltree(tree->left);
        deltree(tree->right);
        free(tree);
    }
}

node* search(node ** tree, int val)
{
    if(!(*tree))
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    if(val < (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->left), val);
    }
    else if(val > (*tree)->data)
    {
        search(&((*tree)->right), val);
    }
    else if(val == (*tree)->data)
    {
        return *tree;
    }
}


int cmp(const void *a, const void *b){
    int x = *(int *)a;
    int y = *(int *)b;
    return x < y ? -1 : x > y;
}

void outToArrayPorder(node *tree, int **arr){
    //pre-order output
    if(tree){
        *(*arr)++ = tree->data;
        outToArrayPorder(tree->left, arr);
        outToArrayPorder(tree->right, arr);
    }
}

void outToArray(node *tree, int **arr){
    //Write elements of tree to the array.
    if(tree){
        outToArray(tree->left, arr);
        *(*arr)++ = tree->data;
        outToArray(tree->right, arr);
    }
}



int main(void) {
    node *root = NULL;
    int i, j;
    node *tmp;
    int arr[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    int arrExp[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)] = {0};
    int arrExp2[] = {55, 31, 1, 4, 49, 39, 47, 64, 65, 98, 97};

    int *aporder = arr;
    int *ap = arrExp;


    // insert 10 nodes on tree
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        insert(&root, arr[i]);

    // check if the array elements are the same of the tree
    outToArray(root, &ap);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    // insert node 4 on tree
    insert(&root, 4);

    // check if tree nodes are now icual to arrExp that has now the 4 node
    outToArray(root, &ap);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    // check if pre order display is icual to ArrExp2
    outToArrayPorder(root, &aporder);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp2[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    tmp = search(&root, 55);
    if (tmp)
    {
        printf("Searched node=%d\n", tmp->data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data Not found in tree.\n");
    }

    /* Deleting all nodes of tree */
    deltree(root);

    return 0;
}
```

To try to fix the issue about the code not be executed when it appears "not same" I was trying like below, without the return -1, but the same issue happens. When it says "not same" the search="55" dont appear because that part its not executed.

```
// insert node 4 on tree
    insert(&root, 4);

    // check if tree nodes are now icual to arrExp2 that has now the 4 node
    int out2[++n];
    ap = out2;
    bool test = true;
    outToArray(root, &ap);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (out2[i] != arrExp2[i]) {
            puts("not same");
           test=false;
        }
    }
    if(test == true){
        puts("same");
    }
```

Comment: Well, `"not same"` is printed, the next line is `return -1;`, so `main()` `return`s a value of `-1`, and the program ends. That is why no more code executes.

Comment: You need to provide a [mcve]. This code will not compile as is, and is missing important functions, such as `insert()`.

Comment: I update the question. This is what I have at this moment and it has the two issues of the question.

Comment: This might have something to do with the fact that your `search` function should return the result of itself when, say, `val < (*tree)->dat`. It actually returns nothing (which *might* be an indefined result).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not consider adding elements.
Change it as like follows.

```
int main(void) {
    node *root = NULL;
    int i;
    int arr[] = {55, 31, 49, 64, 65, 39, 47, 98, 97, 1};
    int n = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    int arrExp1[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr)] = {0};
    int arrExp2[] = {1, 4, 31, 39, 47, 49, 55, 64, 65, 97, 98};
    int arrExp3[] = {55, 31, 1, 4, 49, 39, 47, 64, 65, 98, 97};
    int *ap = arrExp1;

    // insert nodes of arr on tree
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
        insert(&root, arr[i]);

    // check if the array elements are the same of the tree
    outToArray(root, &ap);
    qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (arr[i] != arrExp1[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    // insert node 4 on tree
    insert(&root, 4);

    // check if tree nodes are now icual to arrExp2 that has now the 4 node
    int out2[++n];
    ap = out2;
    outToArray(root, &ap);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (out2[i] != arrExp2[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    // check if pre order display is icual to ArrExp3
    ap = out2;
    outToArrayPorder(root, &ap);
    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        if (out2[i] != arrExp3[i]) {
            puts("not same");
            return -1;
        }
    }
    puts("same");

    node *tmp = search(&root, 55);
    if (tmp)
    {
        printf("Searched node=%d\n", tmp->data);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Data Not found in tree.\n");
    }

    /* Deleting all nodes of tree */
    deltree(root);

    return 0;
}
```

---

For comments.
sample code:

```
n = sizeof(arr2)/sizeof(*arr2);//length of arr2
for (i = 0; i < n; i++)
    insert(&root, arr2[i]);//values of arr2 add to tree

n = print_preorder(root);puts("");//number of elements of tree

int out4[n];//new array for store tree to array
ap = out4;
outToArrayPorder(root, &ap);

if(sizeof(out4) == sizeof(arrExp4) && memcmp(out4, arrExp4, sizeof(out4))==0)//Each size may not be equal.
    puts("same4");
else
    puts("not same");
```

Comment: Thank you. But for example if the "out2[i] != arrExp3[i]" the Searched Node=55 dont appears.

Comment: arrExp1 is 10 elements in size, and the second and third writes will output 11 elements to it. The additional check is a good idea, but until the remaining bugs are fixed, it won't do much good.

Comment: @Jokl If you do not succeed in the examination and you want to continue the next examination, you need to change so that the program does not end.

Comment: @LSerni `n` is incremented. `int out2[++n];` after `insert(&root, 4);`

Comment: Thanks. So if the issue is in the return -1, the solution as I updated should not work?

Comment: @Jokl Your change seems to work. By the way, You can write it using `memcmp` as follows. `if(memcmp(out2, arrExp2, sizeof(out2))==0)
  puts("same");
 else
  puts("not same");`

Comment: Thanks. I have another test that is to add again more nodes on the tree in a for loop. I inserted that nodes and then tried to do the comparision with your method, like this "http://ideone.com/1J5iEk". But this last comparison that I adedd dont work. Im trying to put it work but Im not understanding if it should be that easy or not.

Comment: @Jokl (1) `i < n` is wrong. `n` should be length of `arr2`. (2) `outToArray(root, &ap);` : `ap` should point to New array of the same size as `arr2`. and `outToArrayPorder` instead of `outToArray`. (3) `if(memcmp(arr2, arrExp1, sizeof(arr2))==0)` : `arrExp4` instead  of `arrExp1`. right?

Comment: Thanks again. I did the changes as you suggested but I get "program has stopped working." when I do this "ap = arreExp4;".

Comment: @Jokl Since it is difficult to understand by comment, it is added sample code to answer..

Comment: I think that now is working, but I didnt change ap to point to the new array, so I dont know if it is really ok.

Comment: @Jokl Because `out4` and `arrExp4` are different in size. (And the contents are different. Please compare  output of `print_preorder` with contents of `arrExp4`.)

Answer (score 1):

Currently, your code is designed to **stop** if it is working as apparently expected. You have probably written the test the other way round.

Once the `search` function has been fixed to iterate by returning the result of itself (return search(...)), this code executes:

```
// insert node 4 on tree
insert(&root, 4);

// check if tree nodes are now equal to arrExp that has now the 4 node
```

Now: you are outputting 11 nodes to `ap` which is pointing to an area reserved for 10 numbers. Quite clearly this *cannot* work. In this case it *appears* to work (i.e., it does not crash) because you're overwriting the next variable on the stack.

But even so, you're now comparing an 11-element tree to a 10-element vector (arr). They simply cannot be equal.

(BTW, you do not need to qsort arr again):

```
outToArray(root, &ap);
qsort(arr, n, sizeof(*arr), cmp);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
        puts("not same");
        return -1;
    }
}
puts("same");
```

The above code of course finds the "4" element, which is not in arr, outputs "not same" and stops. You probably wanted:

```
outToArray(root, &ap);
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if (arr[i] != arrExp[i]) {
        break;
    }
}
if (i == n) {
    puts("same. This should not happen");
    exit(1);
} else {
    puts("not same, as expected."); 
}
```

You need to fix arrays to hold space enough to work:

```
int arrExp[sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr) + 2];
```

Then you cannot make `aporder` point to `arr`, since you're going to put 11 elements in it, which would mean write 11 elements to arr, which would overwrite the stack (and the value of root, of all things!).

```
int *aporder = arrExp;
```

Finally, since you do not need to modify the value pointed to, you can simplify the `search()` function. I've added some more debug code:

```
node* search(node *tree, int val)
{
    printf("Start %08lx\n", tree);
    if (tree) {
            if (val < tree->data)
            {
                printf("%d less than %d, going left\n", val, tree->data);
                return search(tree->left, val);
            }
            if(val > tree->data)
            {
                printf("%d more than %d, going right\n", val, tree->data);
                return search(tree->right, val);
            }
    }
    return tree;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But in the last point if we use that approach the "Searched Node=55" dont appears when it shows "same", only appears when "arr[i] != arrExp[i]".

Comment: The third test (the one with preOrder) is botched (@BLUEPIXY has the right of it). If you disable it, you'll see that it works, and finds the nodes searched for. I checked with 55 and 4.